# Installing ubuntu!

Tags: windows

So I am trying to make the switch from Windows 8 to Ubuntu. I am sick of windows 8 and I want to start fresh and learn a new OS. But I need help. Apparently making the switch seems like a rather complicated process. My computer is pre-installed with Windows and it also does not have a disc drive. Any guidance here would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

Answer (score 0):

im also new to Ubuntu. But its easy to install ubuntu beside windows 8.
1. Download image of ubuntu from ubuntu.com
2. Download LinuxLive USB Creator
http://www.linuxliveusb.com/
3. Install Lili in windows
4. grab your USB flash disk and connect it to PC
5. Install downloaded ISO to USB with Lili.
http://www.linuxliveusb.com/en/help/guide

Than just boot your computer from USB. Good luck and have fun :-)

Comment: Along side? Nooo I want to completely format my hdd and get rid of windows 8 and only have ubuntu

Comment: Its no problem. Ubuntu will ask U, if u want to install along side, or just ubuntu and delete windows.

Comment: Wow great. Thank you so much for the speedy replies. Il try this right now

Comment: Your welcome. Let me know, if everything is ok, and if u like Ubuntu as We :-)

Comment: I do have another question. I will admit I am a bit nervous switching 100% to ubuntu. I have a 'gaming' laptop and I was wondering how difficult it is making the switch. Will I lose much functionality with my laptop or have any driver issues? The computer is maybe 8 months old.

Comment: Well its hard to say. Had no problem with drivers yet, but that doesnt mean, that it can be said for all computers. But Ubuntu comunity is amazing and every problem has solution.

Comment: Try it along side windows and u will see. Or try it live, and then install.

Answer (score 0):

I recently installed Ubuntu as well, and it was pretty easy and painless.

1. Download ubuntu from ubuntu.com
2. Download [Pen Drive](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/%22Linux%20Pen%20Drive%20Installer%22) to your USB (Needs 2gb or higher)
3. Run Pen Drive Installer and select the ISO file
4. Insert USB to computer
5. Reboot computer and set the Boot First option to the flash drive in BIOS
6. Follow the on screen instructions.

There will be times when it appears to not be doing anything, but it is working. It will take while so just be patient.

Have fun!!